# Getting error in NodejS when setting the file path

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here what i am doing ,I am getting the file path from

```
 var url = JSON.stringify(req.body.path);
```

which giving me the correct path but when i am using the passing the `url` inside the below chunk of code

```
 fs.createReadStream(url).
    pipe(bucket.openUploadStream('test.apk')).
    on('error', function(error) {
      assert.ifError(error);
    }).
    on('finish', function() {
      console.log('done!');
      res.send("Uploaded Sucessfully..")
      process.exit(0);
    });

};
```

I am getting below error

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'E:\SomeServer\"..\apks\testappV1.0.0.apk"'
>       at Error (native)

but if i am hard coding

```
var url1 = '../apks/testappV1.0.0.apk';
```

the `url1` is working perfdect with the above code why `url` not working i think i am doing some silly mistake not able to find , Can you please point out what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try this './../apks/testappV1.0.0.apk' or __dirname+'../apks/testappV1.0.0.apk'

Comment: None of the above is working !

Comment: can you specify your folder structure?

Comment: Try not to stringify the path. No JSON.stringify.
var url = req.body.path;

Comment: You are right did small mistake didn't realized you can post your answer .

Comment: Posted !!! Hopefully, others can benefit too from this. Glad that you got this figured it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to stringify the path.No JSON.stringify. req.body.path is already a string.

```
var url = req.body.path; 

fs.createReadStream(url).
    pipe(bucket.openUploadStream('test.apk')).
    on('error', function(error) {
      assert.ifError(error);
    }).
    on('finish', function() {
      console.log('done!');
      res.send("Uploaded Sucessfully..")
      process.exit(0);
    });

};
```

Hope this helps.